# How to correctly update QScrollArea when dynamically removing a QLabel from it?

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qlabel, qscrollarea

I'm developing a timeline editor containing tracks represented by `QLabels` in a `QScrollArea`.

First there's a track by default, and we can add and remove tracks dynamically.

I'm having issue with the fact that when there are a few tracks left (3) and I remove one of them, the painting is broken, please see the gif below:

[image]

I've tried :

- `qApp->processEvents()`
- `update()`
- `show()`
- `style()->unpolish(); style()->polish();`

and I applied those methods to all graphical elements implied in this context.

Here is my code description :

- `EditCueTimelineWidget` class is the global widget shown is the image.
- `ui->TimelineEditScrollArea` is the `QScrollArea`.
- `ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents` is the `scrollArea`'s content widget.
- `_trackLabelList` is a `QVector` of `TrackLabel`.
- `_subTrackLabelList` (for each `TrackLabel`) is a `QVector` of `SubTrackLabel`.
- `TrackLabel` and `SubTrackLabel` have a `_label` member which is a `VerticalLabel` (which shows the name vertically) and a `_strip` member which is a `QLabel` with orange or yellow color (showing which track or subtrack is currently selected).

Here's the code

```
void EditCueTimelineWidget::refreshWidget()
{
    qApp->processEvents();
    ui->label->refreshTimemarks();
    for(auto l :qAsConst(_trackLabelList))
    {
        l->recenterWidgets();
        l->update();
        l->show();
    }

    style()->unpolish(ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents);
    style()->polish(ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents);
    style()->unpolish(ui->TimelineEditScrollArea);
    style()->polish(ui->TimelineEditScrollArea);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);

    ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->update();
    ui->TimelineEditScrollArea->update();
    update();
    ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->show();
    ui->TimelineEditScrollArea->show();
    show();

    ui->nbTracksLabel->setText(QString::number(_trackLabelList.size())+tr(" Tracks"));
    qApp->processEvents();
}
```

```
void TrackLabel::recenterWidgets()
{
    _label->setFixedSize(50,height());
    _label->move(40,0);

    _strip->setFixedSize(15, height());
    _strip->move(1,1);

    int nbSub = _subTrackLabelList.size();
    for(int k = 0; k <nbSub ; k++)
    {
        SubTrackLabel* l = _subTrackLabelList.at(k);
        int h = height()/nbSub;
        int posY = k * h;
        if(k != (nbSub -1))
            l->setFixedSize(width() - 100, h);
        else
            l->setFixedSize(width() - 100, height() - posY);
        l->move(100,posY);

        l->recenterWidgets();
        l->update();
        l->show();
    }

    style()->unpolish(_label);
    style()->polish(_label);
    style()->unpolish(_strip);
    style()->polish(_strip);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);

    _label->update();
    _strip->update();
    _label->show();
    _strip->show();
}
```

```
void SubTrackLabel::recenterWidgets()
{
    _label->setFixedSize(35,height());
    _label->move(20,0);

    _strip->setFixedSize(12, height());
    _strip->move(1,1);

    style()->unpolish(_label);
    style()->polish(_label);
    style()->unpolish(_strip);
    style()->polish(_strip);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);

    _label->update();
    _strip->update();
    _label->show();
    _strip->show();
}
```

Note that I have a resizing `eventFilter` on `EditCueTimelineWidget`, and when I resize the application manually, I get the result expected: the two last tracks take all the space and are correctly shown :

```
bool EditCueTimelineWidget::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        refreshWidget();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also note that in `TrackLabel` constructor, I have this :

```
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    setMinimumHeight(300);
```

What method should I call, or should I change call order of  the methods I'm already using, in order to get the result I need?

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem :

when I added a TrackLabel, I called : `ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->layout()->addWidget(l);`
But I didn't removedd it from the layout when take the TrackLabel from the vector and deletelater()
I did it now and it works fine :

```
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->layout()->removeWidget(activeTrack);
```

I wipe all those "refresh painting" method from my code, except for all `show()` which seems to be necessary,
And I kept `qApp->prrocessEvents()` but outside of `refrefhWidget` (it was a bad idea, since I call this method in a resize event, and a lot of `qApp->prrocessEvents()` each time I resize for 1 pixel make it... crash !
I put `qApp->prrocessEvents()` only when I have to do an `ensureWidgetVisible` (have to do it to force recomputing the 'maximum' of the scroll bar or something like that)